# Show values in labels

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

in this code i fetch some values(prices) from a table in reader1 and the next when reader2 is executed i want to show prices in the lables .i want show just executed values price but always the lables shown the all prices .

```
public partial class SingleSeatSaleResult : System.Web.UI.Page
{
string Fruit_price;
string Drink_price;
string Desert_price;
string MainFood_price;
string Salad_price;
string TableFlower_price;
string SaloonLighting_price;
string SaloonDesign_price;
string SaloonCrew_price;
string Pastry_price;
string GiftCard_price;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    using (SqlConnection connection2 = DBConnection.getConnection())
    {
        //query for fetch service prices 
        string strquery2 = "SELECT Fruit_price,Drink_price,Desert_price,MainFood_price,Salad_price,TableFlower_price,SaloonLighting_price,SaloonDesign_price,SaloonCrew_price,Pastry_price,GiftCard_price  FROM GenReservationServicePrice";
        connection2.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
        cmd2.Connection = connection2;
        cmd2.CommandText = strquery2;
        SqlDataReader reader1 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader1.Read())
        {                               
            Fruit_price = reader1[0].ToString();
            Drink_price = reader1[1].ToString();
            Desert_price = reader1[2].ToString();
            MainFood_price = reader1[3].ToString();
            Salad_price = reader1[4].ToString();
            TableFlower_price = reader1[5].ToString();
            SaloonLighting_price = reader1[6].ToString();
            SaloonDesign_price = reader1[7].ToString();
            SaloonCrew_price = reader1[8].ToString();
            Pastry_price = reader1[9].ToString();
            GiftCard_price = reader1[10].ToString();

        }
    }

    using (SqlConnection connection1 = DBConnection.getConnection())
    {          
        string strquery1 = "SELECT (select top 1 'Fruit' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where Fruit=1) as fruit, (select top 1 'Drink' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where Drink=1) as drink, (select top 1 'Desert' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where Desert=1) as desert,(select top 1 'MainFood' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where MainFood=1) as MainFood,(select top 1 'Salad' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where Salad=1) as salad,(select top 1 'TableFlower' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where TableFlower=1) as TableFlower,(select top 1 'SaloonLighting' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where SaloonLighting=1) as SaloonLighting,(select top 1 'Saloondesign' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where Saloondesign=1) as Saloondesign,(select top 1 'SloonCrew' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where SloonCrew=1) as SloonCrew,(select top 1 'Pastry' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where Pastry=1) as Pastry,(select top 1 'GiftCard' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where GiftCard=1) as GiftCard ";
        connection1.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
        cmd1.Connection = connection1;
        cmd1.CommandText = strquery1;
        string cis = Session["customerID"].ToString();
        lbl2_customerid.Text = cis;

        SqlDataReader reader2 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader2.Read())
        {
            if (reader2.GetBoolean(0))

            lbl8_fruit.Text = Fruit_price;


            if (reader2.GetBoolean(1))

            lbl10_drink.Text = Drink_price;


            if (reader2.GetBoolean(2))

            lbl11_desert.Text = Desert_price;


            if (reader2.GetBoolean(3))

            lbl12_mainfood.Text = MainFood_price;



            if (reader2.GetBoolean(4))

            lbl13_salad.Text = Salad_price;


            if (reader2.GetBoolean(5))

            lbl14_tableflower.Text = TableFlower_price;


            if (reader2.GetBoolean(6))

            lbl15_saloonlighting.Text = SaloonLighting_price;


            if (reader2.GetBoolean(7))

            lbl16_saloondesign.Text = SaloonDesign_price;



            if (reader2.GetBoolean(8))

            lbl17_salooncrew.Text = SaloonCrew_price;


            if (reader2.GetBoolean(9))

            lbl18_pastry.Text = Pastry_price;


            if (reader2.GetBoolean(10))

            lbl19_giftcard.Text = GiftCard_price;


        }
    }
 }

}
```

Comment: what do you want from this code ? please elaborate.

Comment: in this code i fetch Prices from a table in reader1 and put them in session  and true values from another table in reader2 . i want when True Values was fetched in reader2 , the prices show in lables . in other word , i want show only True Values Prices not all . this code like saleresult

Comment: are you matching value from reader2 to in reader1 ?

Comment: thats being said yes im matching value from reader1 to in reader2 . in other word i want : if query return true value , i show a price for that ,else , show nothing

Comment: why are you not use any condition in the code ? How can i justify how to match it

Comment: in updated code i add condition but only show me the first value(Fruit) .

Comment: You shouldn't use a session to store data from database. Also you should really work on your names.

Comment: i cant use values in the reader2 scope . the values only can use in reader1 scope ,for that i put them in the session and now i can use them anywhere . now what should i do? i test with step by step debuging and i under stand only if no.1 was run and other was not runed

Comment: You don't have to use a session for this, you can just declare the variables "Fruit_price", "Drink_price", etc. BEFORE the using statement.

Comment: see my updated code , i remove session and else if was changed to if, but again i have that problem .

Comment: I am not quite sure if I understand it correctly. You have a reader which fetches data from something you called "AllPrices" and another reader that fetches data from something you called "TruePrices". And if a "TruePrice" exists for a certain column, you want the label to use this instead of the value from "AllPrices" ?

Comment: no , i want when a true value fetched , its prices fetched and show in label too , not all price . for example i select salad and fruit , i want show only salad and fruit prices in lables not all items price.

Comment: So what you basically want is a string concatenation?
You could write lbl8_fruit.Text = reader2[0].ToString();
            lbl8_fruit.Text += Fruit_price;

Comment: no i dont want concatenation , i just want show only that values price 
Those what contain True values . for example i select fruit and drink , in the database placed True values for drink and fruit . so in reader2 when true values was fetched , show a price for that . Eventually show only drink  and fruit price not all items price

Comment: I have edited my answer, please check and tell me if it fixed your problem. The value of this column has to be a bit (in the database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the second of these two statements your are replacing the lbl8_Fruit's Text-Property:

```
lbl8_fruit.Text = reader2[0].ToString();
lbl8_fruit.Text = Fruit_price;
```

**EDIT**
You can read a boolean with the SqlDataReader with the method *GetBoolean(index)*. So for example:

```
if (reader2.GetBoolean(0)) { 
    lbl8_fruit.Text = Fruit_price;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I should  not index and all getboolean should wrote (0)?

Comment: i test this code and i give answer but the "fruit" was shown .                         if (reader2[0].ToString() != null && reader2[0].ToString() != "")
                    lbl8_fruit.Text = reader2[0].ToString() + Fruit_price;